# How to kill LESS for git log in shell script while loop?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, scripting, git-log

I want to monitor my git log using a shell script but I cannot figure out how to send the `q` key to kill LESS to continue the while loop.  Here is what I have so far:

```
while :
do
clear
git log
sleep 1
done
```

I also tried:

```
while :
do
clear
git log
PID=$!
sleep 1
kill $PID
done
```

But, that second script has the same problem as the one before it, which is that the loop stops and waits for the git log (which is being shown through LESS) to quit.

How can I send a command to quit the git log so that it can refresh?

Comment: Why is `git log` running `vim` at all? Have you configured `git` to use `vim` as your pager? The simple answer is to not use an interactive program in a script that isn't supposed to be interactive.

Comment: @chepner, every machine i have ever encountered that ive used git on uses vim by default to display the log. it might be another program like less, im not sure but either way it would be the same process, right?

Comment: I'm not sure who is configuring your machines, but I've never seen one that uses an editor as the *default* pager.

Comment: There is quite a difference between `vim` and `less`.

Comment: Do you want the `--no-pager` option on `git log`?

Comment: yes, that seems to work with the script! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With @chepners help, here is the solution that works for me to monitor the log without the watch command:

```
while :
do
clear
git --no-pager log
sleep 1
done
```